# visa entry to Amsterdam for a layover

Tags: visas

am coming back from Sudan to Canada and I have a 6 hours layover in Amsterdam  and I have a Canadian travel document do I need a visa there

Comment: Do you want to leave the international zone of the airport? The visa requirements are different depending.

Comment: @MadHatter the suggested duplicate entirely ignores the issue of refugee travel documents. It's also unclear whether the traveler here wants to pass through passport control.

Comment: @phoog I completely agree; I'd merely thought it would be better to bring what looks increasingly like the standard answer up to full completeness than to scatter the advice amongst an increasing number of specific questions.

Comment: Agreed with @MadHatter voted to close let's figure it out in the 41-upvoted central question than here.